# Ajax with jquery to set time interval

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a notification message i want to load new message from a page call `check_new-reply.php` in every 10 second using Ajax and Jquery but my code is not showing anything i don't know what the error is please can someone help me out?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
var timer = 10;
var test = "";
function inTime(){
    setTimeOut(inTime, 1000);
    $("#timer-u").html("Time refreshing"+timer);
    if(timer == 8){
        $("#message-u").html("Loading....");
        $.POST("check_new_reply.php",{testing:test}, function(data){
        $("#message-u").html(data); 
    })
        timer = 11;
        clearTimeout(inTime);
    }
    timer--;
}
inTime();
   });
});
</script>
```

Here is PHP

```
<?php include($root . '_inc/Initialization.php');?> 
<?php require_once("_inc/dbcontroller.php"); $db_handle = new DBController();?>

<?php 
$users = $_SESSION['username'];
$newquery = "SELECT * FROM blog_post
        INNER JOIN replys
        ON blog_post.UserName = '$users'
        WHERE replys.read = 0
        ORDER BY rtime";
        $newhisory =  mysql_query($newquery);
        while($newrow =  mysql_fetch_array($newhisory)){
echo '<div class="fnot"><a href="/questions/postid/'.$newrow['BID'].'" id="readme">'.htmlentities($newrow['blog_title']).'</a>'; 
echo '<span class="ttcredit"><font color="darkgreen">94</font> </span> <a class="reqttag reqttag2" href="#">No</a> ';
echo '</div>';
echo '<input type="hidden" id="unr" name="unr" value="'.$newrow['BID'].'"/>';
}

?>
```

Comment: you're missing a semi-colon after the parenthesis above timer=11. Also I think .POST should be lower case

Comment: Try moving `setTimeout` (notice my capitalization) out of the `inTime` function.

Comment: Please give me example of what you are saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to call it every 10 seconds, use `10000` milliseconds in the `setTimeOut` . Also, it is best to call again the function only when the previous Ajax call is done:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
    var test = "";
    function inTime(){
        $.POST("check_new_reply.php",{testing:test}, function(data){
            $("#message-u").html(data); 
            setTimeout(inTime, 10000);
        });
    }
    inTime();
    });
});
```

Comment: Is still not loading the datas @Ralph

Comment: try to `console.log("Ajax Called");` inside the $.post callback. If there are consoles every 10 seconds, then the problem is not in the script. its in your PHP .

Comment: John Please i'm new in web development can you show me how i can do that should i attach my PHP in my question?

Comment: yes please add your PHP `check_new_reply.php` . Lets check.

Comment: @Micheal i edited my answer , change `setTimeOut` to `setTimeout`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103047/discussion-between-micheal-and-ralph-john-galindo).

Answer (score 0):

To call any function with some intervals you will have to use

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.setInterval(function(){
            myAjaxCall();
        }, 10000);
    });

    function myAjaxCall() {
        alert("Hi");
        $("#message-u").html("Loading....");
        $.POST("check_new_reply.php",{testing:test}, function(data){
            $("#message-u").html(data); 
        });
    }
</script>
```

window.setInterval will call your function on every 3 seconds with above code, and will generate an alert message,
what you have to do is set your ajax code in a function and use above method, change 3000 to 10000 and your ajax call will defiantly work with every 10 seconds,

Comment: I just tried your answer is still the same can you show on snippet or do i need to include any jquery libery link in my website before it work?

Comment: yeah, if you are using any jquery code then you must include any jquery at top ,. , have you added  ? ?

Comment: i made an example, in which my function was called in every 10 seconds and generates an alert. you want it. ? just copy it in individual file and you will get an idea,

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which will call our javascript function on every 10 seconds, 
just copy it and check it, you will get an idea, also i have included the jquery as we have discussed.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.setInterval(function(){
            myAjaxCall();
        }, 3000);
    });

    function myAjaxCall() {
        alert("Call your Ajax here");
        $("#message-u").html("Loading....");
        $.POST("check_new_reply.php",{testing:test}, function(data){
            $("#message-u").html(data); 
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Pinit but is not loading data from php page

Comment: remove the alert and let ajax post execute.  check in the firebug that is your ajax call executing or not from xhr.